# mod_rewrite changing .htaccess to convert php to html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I was looking for a .htaccess that rewrites all my .php files from a specific folder.

For example when i access filename.html to show me filename.php(parsed and executed) and when i access filename.php to give me 404. This it what i have so far

```
Options +Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

and belive me that i searched before. It doesn't work ...

Is this actually posible?

Can you have a solution for that please?

Thank you!

Comment: First; You say from a specific folder, but your rewrite base is set to the root. Second; doesn't it work at all, or just that it doesn't give a 404. Third; why do you want to keep the .html in the url. Why not just remove it entirely.

Comment: for SEO propouses, i have a php that combines trough a xslt a xsl with a xml, but it will be great instead of .PHP to have a .HTML, and yes, it dosent work ... when i access filename.php works, filename.html dont

Comment: `[^.]`, does'nt that means "NOT ANY CHARACTER", try with `[^\.]`

Comment: Search engines don't mind if the url ends in html, php, or doesn't have an extension at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that something like this would work:

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php [L]